# Exibir e modificar itens no banco de dados com php

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: Esse e o painel para editar as informações]

Preciso exibir os valores do banco de dados nesses campos de input e tambem edita-los, ja tenho a coluna criada, com **Titulo** & **AdsCode** nome da tabela é **site**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é sua classe de conexão com o banco? Você usa `mysql_*` (obsoleta), `mysqli_*` ou `PDO`

Comment: mysql_* (obsoleta). estou utilizando o PHP 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As funções `mysql_*` estão obsoletas e foram removidas no PHP 7, porém as mysqli_* são semelhantes, vou mostrar um exemplo com mysqli...

[Conexão](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.construct.php):

```
//inicia uma conexão com o banco, note que aqui ja é selecionado o banco de dados
$con = new mysqli("server", "user", "pass", "db_name");

//Caso algum erro ocorra mostra o erro
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
```

[Consulta no padrão STMT](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

```
//Prepara o SQL
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM site");

//Executa o SQL
$stmt->execute();

//Obtem o resultado do SQL
$res = $stmt->get_result();
```

Para mostrar o SQL tem várias formas...

**[`fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)** - Guarda o resultado em um array em outro array:

```
$array = $res->fetch_all();
echo $array[x][y];
```

`x` - linha da consulta

`y` - coluna da consulta

Por exemplo, `$array[0][2]` retorna o id (coluna na posição 2) da primeira linha da consulta (linha da posição 0), lembrando sempre que o array começa na posição 0, ou seja, posição 0 = 1°, posição 1 = 2°, ...

**[`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)** - Guarda uma linha em um array, geralmente é usado um loop para pegar todas as linhas:

```
while($array = $res->fetch_row()) {
    echo "$array[0], $array[1], $array[2]<br>";
}
```

Mostra todos nomes, adscode e id, o `<br>` é apenas para visualizar melhor

**[`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** - Funciona da mesma forma que o `fetch_row`, porém em vez de pegar a posição do array, é pego pelo nome denominado pelo banco:

```
while($array = $res->fetch_row()) {
    echo $array["titulo"]." (".$array["id"].") - ".$array["adscode"]."<br>"
}
```

No `fetch_assoc` não é necessário usar na ordem das colunas do banco, mas não da pra usar interpolação (variável no meio da string, `"texto $variavel mais texto"`), causa erro

**[`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)** - Guarda os dados em um array, pode ser usado tanto `$array["coluna"]` como `$array[x]`:

```
while($array = $res->fetch_array()) {
    echo $array["titulo"]." (".$array["id"].") - $array[2]<br>";
}
```

No `fetch_array` pode ser usado interpolação nos números

**[`fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)** - Retorna um objeto com os dados:

```
while($array = $res->fetch_object()) {
    echo "$array->titulo ($array->id) - $array->adscode<br>";
}
```

No `fetch_object` é posssível usar interpolação tranquilamente

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um arquivo php com o código abaixo:

```
<?php 

include("conexaoMysql.php");

class Result{
    public $titulo;
    public $adscode;

}

function getResultado($conn){
    $sqlf = "
        SELECT titulo,adscode FROM tabela
    ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlf);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($titulo, $anuncio);

    while(($stmt->fetch()) ){
        $result = new Result();

        $result->numero = $titulo;
        $result->data = $anuncio;

        $listaResult[] = $result;
    }

    return $listaResult;
}   

try{
    $listaResult = getResultado($conn);  
}catch (Exception $e){
    $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Caso seja mais de uma linha de registros, criei a variavel $listaResult para armazenar todos os registros.

Essa linha: "include("conexaoMysql.php");" se refere a um arquivo com os dados de conexão com o banco, criei apenas para facilitar, mas seria mais ou menos assim, caso esteja usando SQL:

```
<?php
$HOST = "";
$USER = "";
$PASSWORD = "";
$DATABASE = "";

$conn = new mysqli($HOST, $USER, $PASSWORD, $DATABASE);

if ($conn->connect_error)
    throw new Exception('Falha na conexão com o MySQL: ' . $conn->connect_error);
?>
```

Comment: não deu certo estou tentando exibir <?php echo $titulo; ?> da variavel indefinida

Comment: Edita a pergunta adicionando o código que tem até o momento.

Comment: Poste o código do seu arquivo que faz conexão com o banco.